# Errors ms access vba email report

Tags: vba, ms-access

I keep getting an error when I run this code.

```
Sub SendEmailMaturing()
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim db As Database
    Dim strSQL As String

    Set db = CurrentDb

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM qRespCodeEmail"
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
        rs.MoveFirst
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            'Debug.Print rs.Fields("RMName")
            DoCmd.OpenReport "Maturing Loans in 90", acViewPreview, , "RespName = " & rs!RMName
            DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "Maturing Loans in 90", acFormatPDF, rs!Email, , , "Maturing Loans", "Kindly take a look and send me an update on the status of matured loans.", True
            DoCmd.Close acReport, "Maturing Loans in 90", acSaveNo

            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have tried many things but no success

Comment: When you ask a question on StackOverflow, you are expected to show your work and what you've tried, including what exact error you've gotten.

Comment: Which error excatly did you receive? In which line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are filtering on a text field, use apostrophe delimiters for parameter:

`DoCmd.OpenReport "Maturing Loans in 90", acViewPreview, , "RespName = '" & rs!RMName & "'"`

Use # for date/time fields, nothing for number type.

Could reduce amount of data pulled by including just necessary fields in SQL statement. Appears you need only RMName and Email.